# Trie SPOJ Problem - PhoneList TLE

Tags: java, optimization, algorithm, strings, trie

In this problem you are given input of phone numbers and you are supposed to determine whether any number is the prefix of another. I have an `addchild` method that returns true or false if a given string can be inserted and is not a prefix of another string. How could I improve the efficiency of my code so that I could pass the time constraints?

http://www.spoj.com/problems/PHONELST/

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

class PhoneList {

static class Node{
    Node [] children;

    int value;

    public Node(){
        children=new Node[11];
    }

    public Node(int value){
        children=new Node[11];
        this.value=value;
    }

}

static class  Trie{
    Node root=null;

    public Trie(){
        root=new Node();
    }

    boolean addChild(String s){

        Node currentNode=root;
        int number=0;

        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
            number=s.charAt(i)-'0';
            if(currentNode.children[currentNode.children.length-1]!=null){
                return false;
            }
            if(currentNode.children[number]==null){
                currentNode.children[number]=new Node(number);
            }
            currentNode=currentNode.children[number];
        }

        if(currentNode.children[currentNode.children.length-1]==null){
            currentNode.children[currentNode.children.length-1]=new Node(10);
        }else{
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

    int number_of_test_cases=input.nextInt();

    boolean istrue;
    for(int i=0;i<number_of_test_cases;i++){

        Trie tree=new Trie();
        int length=input.nextInt();
        String numbers[]=new String[length];

        for(int j=0;j<numbers.length;j++){
            numbers[j]=input.next();
        }

        Arrays.sort(numbers);
        istrue=true;

       for(int k=0;k<numbers.length;k++){
        if(!tree.addChild(numbers[k])){
            System.out.println("NO");
            istrue=false;
            break;
        }
        }

        if(istrue){
            System.out.println("YES");
        }
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Instead of `children = new Node[11]`, I would use a `Map<Integer, Node>`.  I'm not sure how you came up with 11.
- Sorting is quite expensive.  Maybe you can solve it with a trie alone without sorting, or with sorting alone without a trie.
- Small detail: you have random gaps of 2, 3 or 4 empty lines all over the place.

---

**EDIT**:
So, instead of arguing, here is my implementation, without sorting and without a terminal value:

```
    public static class Node<T> {
        private T value;
        private Map<T, Node<T>> children = new HashMap<>();

        public Node(T value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public Node<T> getChild(T t) {
            return children.get(t);
        }

        public boolean hasChildren() {
            return !children.isEmpty();
        }

        public void addChild(T t, Node<T> child) {
            children.put(t, child);
        }
    }

    public static boolean hasConflictingPrefixes(String[] numbers) {
        Node<Byte> trie = new Node<>(null);
        for (String number : numbers) {
            Node<Byte> currentNode = trie;
            for (Byte byt : number.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))) {
                Node<Byte> childNode = currentNode.getChild(byt);
                if (childNode == null) {
                    childNode = new Node(byt);
                    currentNode.addChild(byt, childNode);
                } else {
                    // current number is longer (or equal) to existing word
                    if (!childNode.hasChildren()) 
                        return true;
                }
                currentNode = childNode;
            }
            // current number is a prefix to another one
            if (currentNode.hasChildren())  
                return true;
        } 
        return false;
    }
```

I'm not necessarily proud of this code, but it solves this problem.

Note that duplicate numbers are considered as conflicting prefixes, ie. {"911", "911"} has a conflict just as {"911", "9112"}.

Comment: I came up with 11 because 0-9 are going to be mapped to a node that is used in a phone number and the node with index 10 signifies that a specific phone number ended.

Comment: How would using a Collection make it faster?

Comment: It's not faster, but cleaner.

Comment: This still doesn't solve the problem at hand...the algorithm is too slow

Comment: I did not mean a Collection, but a `Map`. (Edited my answer.)

Comment: About the speed, have you read my second point about sorting?  I added it after the initial post.

Comment: I don't think you need the 11th index, since if a node is a terminal node, it is obvious from its lack of children.

Comment: In the construction of a trie a terminal node is needed because you can have more than one string that starts with the same prefix

Comment: Not for this particular problem, since everything breaks down when one number is the prefix of another.  As I just wrote, you can tell if a node is terminal by looking if it has children.

Comment: In a trie if you don't have a terminal node then you wouldn't be able to tell how many strings there are that start with the same prefix...

Comment: ex: 9114 and 911 - in your case if there is no terminal node the trie would only contain 9114 acting as if there is only one string in the trie

Comment: @The Bear Wrong. And wrong to the one who upvoted your comments.  See my solution.

Comment: I see my mistake in reasoning. This code solves this problem, but for a regular trie that has other applications there would need to be some kind of terminal node?

Comment: I'm not trie expert, but I believe there would have to be some flag to indicate that a node can be terminal even when it still has children.

Comment: How come you said "I'm not necessarily proud of this code" ...I thought it was pretty good

Comment: I was vaguely thinking about the missing flag indicating termination (what we where discussing above).  You could not use that in general for a trie.

Comment: This answer gives TLE as well